# A better alternative to ng-switch?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to dynamically load a directive template based on a condition, in my case the `type` attribute from directive scope. The template that is being loaded looks like this:

```
<div ng-switch="type">
    <div ng-switch-when="player" ...></div>
    <div ng-switch-when="npc" ...></div>
</div>
```

After reading some related questions, I have found that there is a way that I can do what ng-switch does, but within the directive itself. I have tried to use vanilla JS switch inside a function that replaced the template string within the directive, but with no success, my guess would be due to the fact that I was using a scope attribute  as the switch condition.

Being new to Angular makes finding and understanding solutions to my problem quite difficult, so if I didnt explain my issue with enough clarity, let me know.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I find that switch quite elegant TBH... What's the issue of using it?

Comment: can you show what you have tried?

Comment: @sp00m There's no issue, ng-switch works fine. Afte reading some related questions I was thinking that there is a way I could accomplish the same behaviour without an external html file and do all the templating within the directive

Comment: @ShivamTiwari What I tried was basically a switch function inside the directive template that based on the condition being met would return the template to be loaded as a string.

Comment: that should work, based on switch form a  HTML string and use $compile service to link scope to the resultant template.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile